# Visualforce Page using Wrapper class in pageblocktable and apex repeat

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class, pageblocktable

**Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.lstWrp'**    I am trying to understand how does the pageblock table loop the repeat. I have done a similar page to account , contact object it worked fine but not with wrappers.

```
<apex:page controller="vendorDashboard" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <body>
        <apex:slds />
    </body>
    <apex:pageBlock id="mainBlock">
        <apex:repeat value="{!lstWrap}" var="acc">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!acc.SectionName}" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstWrap.lstWrp}" var="a">
                    <apex:column value="{!a.FieldName}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.FieldValue}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class vendorDashboard{
    public list<WrapSection> lstWrap{get;set;}    
    public vendorDashboard(){
        lstWrap = new list<WrapSection>();         
        list<WrapFields> lw = new list<WrapFields>();
        list<WrapFields> lw2 = new list<WrapFields>();        
        WrapFields WF = new WrapFields();
        WF.FieldName = 'field1';
        WF.FieldValue = 'value1';
        lw.add(WF);
        WrapFields WF1 = new WrapFields();
        WF1.FieldName = 'field2';
        WF1.FieldValue = 'value2';
        lw.add(WF1);
        WrapFields WF3 = new WrapFields();
        WF3.FieldName = 'field3';
        WF3.FieldValue = 'value3';
        lw.add(WF3);
        WrapFields WF4 = new WrapFields();
        WF4.FieldName = 'field4';
        WF4.FieldValue = 'value4';
        lw2.add(WF4);        
        WrapSection WS = new WrapSection(lw,'Section1');
        WrapSection WS2 = new WrapSection(lw2,'Section2');
        lstWrap.add(WS);
        lstWrap.add(WS2);
    }
    public class WrapFields{
        public string FieldName{get;set;}
        public string FieldValue{get;set;}    
    }
    public class WrapSection{
        public list<WrapFields> lstWrp{get;set;}
        public string SectionName{get;set;}
        public WrapSection(list<WrapFields> lstWrp1,string SectionName1){
            this.lstWrp = lstWrp1;
            this.SectionName = SectionName1;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build page in this format
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to access the "acc" variable, which contains the list in each section wrapper:

```
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc.lstWrp}" var="a">
```

Comment: @SFDCJoe No problem! Sometimes we all just need a "second pair of eyes" when we've been staring too long.

Comment: @SFDCJoe If fox's answer solved your issue, please mark it so by click the checkmark icon.  Thanks!